# Angular no reconoce un efecto de texto

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap

Tengo un problema muy simple pero como estoy iniciando en Angular no sé cómo resolverlo. Cuando pongo el encabezado de mi página no se me reconoce el efecto "máquina de escribir" del subtítulo (tampoco se muestra el texto en la página). El código es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="hero-container" data-aos="fade-in">
      <h1>Jésica Álvarez</h1> 
      <p><span class="typed" data-typed-items="Lic. en Psicopedagogía, Web Developer Junior, Freelancer"></span></p>
    </div>
```

Lo mismo pasa con las barras de progreso que no se cargan.

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: podrías compartir tu css del efecto?

Comment: y el efecto de css?

Comment: Se más específica sobre tu problema y entre más información puedas compartir tu problema con el código recibirás mayor ayuda de la comunidad